# What is the best way to perform basic calculations (% of total) across dataframes in a list?

Tags: r, list, dataframe, plyr

Consider a list of dataframes called `listDF`. Each of the dataframes has the same columns:

`"Date" "Location" "V1" "V2"`   where V1 is a column filled with real numbers

I would like to calculate the % of total of say V1 for each Date/Location combination. That is sum V1 across all dataframes for each specific Date/Location pair and then calculate the share each V1 observation is of the relevant sample.

## What I've tried:

I stack the dataframes because I don't know how to do the sweeping without looping through the Dataframe/Date/Location combinations which is clearly inefficient.

`library(plyr)`

`aggregate <- rbind.fill(listDF)`

`ptt <- ddply(aggregate,.(Date,Location),transform, share= V1/sum(V1))`

The last line leads to RStudio crashing and asking me to start a new session. FWIW, the avg dataframe has 50k rows and the list has about 1M rows total. Should I be using `prop.table`?

In an ideal world, I would have the percent to total (ptt) as a column in each dataframe, instead of in a single stacked dataframe which I would have to split after.

*Side question: is there a way to choose which subset of list elements to use for any given ptt? I've assumed using all dataframes in my initial question but would love to choose based on critera of say V2.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: make your question reproducible

Comment: "instead of in a single stacked dataframe which I would have to split after." Why would you have to split it? Almost all problems in R are most easily addressed with stacked data. By the way, dplyr has replaced plyr within the hadleyverse (that is, the universe of packages by Hadley).

Comment: @Frank Thanks for the comment, I'll use dplyr. I wanted to maintain the split structure in the list of dataframes mainly because when I tried the method outlined above my session would crash. At first I thought it was a memory issue (since stacked it is 1M+ rows) but I don't think it is the issue. In the end I'm hoping to export each dataframe in separate files but to your point that doesn't preclude the actual analysis from occurring in a single dataframe.

Answer (score 1):

If each data frame in the list has the same columns, it would be easier to work with a single data frame that has an extra variable indicating the original data frame. Then you can easily perform calculations grouped by data frame.

**sample data**

```
# two data frames
d1 <- data.frame(x = rep(LETTERS[1:2], each = 5), y = rnorm(10))
d2 <- data.frame(x = rep(LETTERS[1:2], each = 7), y = rnorm(14))

# put data frames in a list
L <- list(d1, d2)
```

We can use `dplyr::bind_rows()` to "unlist" `L` into a single data-frame. The `.id` option instructs `bind_rows` to create an explicit variable identifying the original data frame:

```
library(dplyr)
d <- bind_rows(L, .id = "dat")
```

Now you can do any summary grouped by the variable you created:

```
d %>%
  group_by(dat) %>%
  summarise(mean_y = mean(y))
```

Comment: Thanks @DMC . Which version of dplyr do I need? After I install it I am unable to have bind_rows recognized. Also can you elaborate how I would do the percent to total within the solution you provided?

Comment: Did you load the package: `library(dplyr)`? If you loaded the package and `bind_rows()` is not visible, then install a new version of `dplyr`.

Comment: I did @DMC. I'm using slightly older versions of RStudio and Eclipse. When I install `dplyr` I see it is version 0.2 whereas I've seen version 0.4 online. Is this the discrepancy in being able to use `bind_rows` ? If so, how can I download the latest version? I've closed out sessions and tried re-installing the package.

Comment: Yes, I imagine you need a newer version of `dplyr`. Use `install.packages("dplyr")`. You probably want to get a newer version of RStudio as well.

Comment: Thanks @DMC. The newer version of R corrected this. In fact the code I had outlined initially works with the `plyr` package but I'd like to still figure out how to use the `dplyr`.

Would I do what you suggested and then use `summarise(prop = V1/sum(V1))` ? It's not immediate to me how I should group on Location/Date within the stacked dataframe. And then what would be the best way to send the calculations back appropriately to the separate dataframes from which those observations came from?

Comment: I'm arguing that you should no longer use separate data frames. I would recommend reading the [dplyr vignette](https://cran.rstudio.com/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/introduction.html), especially the section on grouping. And be very careful about loading both `plyr` and `dplyr` into the same R session. This can cause problems with function collisions.